# Issue with remember-me persistent token

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I have a issue when implement spring security remember-me persistent token. 
Already successful implement remember-me persistent token, but issue occurs when user logout of system.

Here are implementation:
spring-security.xml

```
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    ...some url parten
    <form-login login-page="/login.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationHandler"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" delete-cookies='JSESSIONID' />
    <remember-me services-ref="pfRememberMeServices" 
                                        key="pf_token_key"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="pfRememberMeServices" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
      <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="pfTokenRepository" />
      <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
      <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="86400"/> <!-- alive in 1 day -->
      <beans:property name="key" value="pf_token_key" />
      <beans:property name="cookieName" value="mycookie" />
      <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
 </beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.platform.authenticate.model.UserDetailsServiceImpl" >
</beans:bean>.
```

Token repository:

```
    @Override
public void removeUserTokens(String userid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tokenDao.removeUserTokens(userid);
}
```

TokenDao:

```
    @Transactional
public void removeUserTokens(final String username) {
    //Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Token token =
               (Token) session.createCriteria(Token.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username)).uniqueResult();
        if (token != null) {
            session.delete(token);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw e; // or display error message
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

When I login with the same user on two browsers, or two clients, there are two records in persistent_logins table as following:

```
"2JLIh8E8vifKOdlaidCIog==";"user12";"OKjbqqIAhx74JpmPsNQHaw==";"2013-07-03 16:19:05.12"
"gQ2EDtl87ZC6XSjV6cTYrA==";"user12";"iYrG7dlnjPyKxUz/hwQMdQ==";"2013-07-03 15:47:24.011"
```

**Is my implementation is right when there are two record for the same user?**

Then, when I logout from one browser, or one client, the removeUserTokens() function is fired, but:

```
    Token token =
           (Token) session.createCriteria(Token.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username)).uniqueResult();
```

with above code, I could not remove token for logout user by username, when there are 2 records of user12, it is not unique result.

If I force delete all user12, then all session/token for all clients will be deleted. It is not right?

**So how could I remove session/token info for logout user only, but keep session/token for same user on others client?**

I have already ask mr google but my issue is seem to be unique, could not find any same one out there.

If my implementation is wrong, please let me know.

**Update:**
Here are stack trace when I send j_spring_security_logout from one client:

> exception
>
> org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique
>   result: 2
>     org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueElement(AbstractQueryImpl.java:899)
>     org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)

Comment: Anybody have the same issue like me? Is my implementation wrong?

Comment: Im now implementing to remove all user token once user logout. It means all client for same user will be removed. Not my expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I got same implementation - i got same problem.

But no i decide to delete all tokens, because to look up token for definitely

```
    List<Token> tokens = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Token.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username)).list();
    if (tokens.size() > 0) {
        for (Token token : tokens) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(token);
        }
    }
```